# R sample(): incorrect number of probabilities

Tags: r, sample

I am subsampling as follows using R's sample() function.

```
x <- 100 
y <- 10
probs <- c(rep(0.30, 3), rep(0.10/7, 7))

prop.y <- 0.05 

subset.y <- sort(sample(y, size = ceiling(prop.y * y), replace = FALSE))

sample(subset.y, size = x, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[subset.y])
```

When I run the above lines of code I get the error

```
Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

The issue stems from the last line of code.

In this case, subset.y contains the integer data type (e.g., 1L).

However when prop.y is greater than 1 / y, say 0.11, there is no issue. In this instance, subset.y contains the int data type of length 2.

Could someone explain this?

Comment: The `prob` argument should have the same length as the value of `subset.y` if `length(subset.y)==1`. If `length(subset.y)==1`, then `sample` will draw from the values `1:subset.y`. Do you want `sample` instead to just return `subset.y`?

Comment: Yes, I think you are suggesting what I am in need of. I think I would need to include an explicit 'if' statement to handle such cases.

Comment: That's certainly one way of doing it. You may also be interested in the `resample` function found in the examples in `?sample` that deals with exactly this issue.

Comment: I found the resample function: resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]. I will play around with it for my example. Thanks.